# bootstrap - open drop down menu and submenu at specific menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used drop down menu and drop down submenu (only 2 levels) and user can click into drop down sub menu and choose an item they want.

Example:

- Level 1.1

  - Level 1.2.1
  - Level 1.2.2
  - Level 1.2.3  (User click here)
- Level 1.2

Then I store the sub menu item ID where user clicked (1.2.3) and add a button outside of drop down menu, then when user click into this button, the drop down and sub drop down according to sub menu item ID will be open.

Now I only can open Level 1 menu by

```
$("#menu1").dropdown('toggle');
```

but don't know how to open sub drop down menu.

here is the example, that I used: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

but I just want to use to level 2 drop down menu item.

Comment: Show us ya code!  Html and jQuery.  Consider a jsFiddle?

Comment: I've added the example, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$document.ready(function() { 
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this)  // triggered on hover
            .children('.sub-menu')
            .slidedown(200);
        },
        function() {
            $(this) // triggered on hover end
                .children('.sub-menu')
                .slideup(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can assume that op wants a solution that would work on multiple devices #bootstrap .hover won't work on touch devices

Comment: @RamachandraReddy The links which you provided will not work some time. Better you post the code. It ll be useful to everyone. If you need to add benefits to the webpage add the link as reference. Edit it in the answer instead of adding it in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by myself. What you need to know is the ID of sub menu and the important class "open" - without this sub menu will not open programmatically.

In the button to click to show the dropdown menu, you need:

```
 $('#txt_rgb_red_change').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $("#menu1").dropdown('toggle');

     ID_HANDLE_HERE // see below

 });
```

It will open the dropdown menu but without submenu. When user already clicked into sub drop down menu item (you can handle this event with

```
$(".dropdown-submenu").bind("mouseenter",function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // get the id of drop-down menu item
});
```

here is HTML example of this id:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
<li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-toggle" id="sub_dropdown_1" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">Band 1 - 50</a>
....
</li>
</ul>
```

here is sub_dropdown_1, then you can add the class to ID_HANDLE_HERE like this, it must be added correctly to the `<li>`.

```
$("#sub_dropdown_1").parent("ul").parent("li").addClass('open')
```